# svn, can't remove a directory

Tags: linux, svn, fedora

I am on Fedora 17 trying to use svn version 1.7.6

I have created a repository at `/home/el/svnworkspace` and I checked out a working copy in `/workspace`

I am getting this error when I use the command:

```
[root@defiant workspace]# svn remove TestProject --force
```

Gives the Error:

```
svn: E155035: '/workspace/TestProject' 
              is the root of a working copy and cannot be deleted
```

The error message is partially right, `TestProject` was a root before.  But I deleted it and now `/workspace` the root.  So somehow it is confused.  I no longer want TestProject to be a root, and I want workspace to be the root.  svn is confused, and I want to unconfuse it, maybe one of you know the proper wizard incantation to remove `/workspace/TestProject` as a root of a working copy?  I just want it to be a normal folder again.

Perhaps the only way for me to fix it is to blow everything away and re-add everything.  Maybe a resident wizard knows a better way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SVN does get confused about directories sometimes.

Unless you have a lot of changes you need to check in, I suggest removing the hierarchy in question from your filesystem (rm -rf), and checking out again starting from wherever looks appropriate.  This always seems to handle SVN directory confusion for me.

Answer (score 1):

**I was able to fix the problem with these steps:**

Make sure nothing has a lock on the files in question, for me: Eclipse IDE.  So close any IDE's or Editors that might have a lock on the file.

Make sure you have write permissions on the working copy as well as the repository.

```
chmod -R 775 /workspace
chown -R your_user_name.your_user_name 775 /workspace
chmod -R 775 /home/el/svnworkspace
chown -R your_user_name.your_user_name 775 /home/el/svnworkspace
```

If you are using a program with a GUI like `rapidsvn` to add/remove/commit files, turn that off and use only the command line svn command.  The GUI might have been have been conflicting with what I was trying to do on the command line.

**finally, I think this part is what fixed my problem:**

Go into the directory that I want to add, but won't add.  Manually `rm -rf` all the `.svn` files in it.  Then try to svn remove it then svn add it.  It successfully adds and then I could commit it and all is well.